# Getting the date of the next day in PureScript

Tags: date, purescript

Is there anyway to write the following function more elegantly?

I can see some patterns but I'm not sure how to abstract them or how to find a simpler way to write the function.

```
type HasRemainder = Boolean

tomorrow :: Date -> Date
tomorrow date = unsafePartial $ canonicalDate y (fst m) (fst d)
  where d :: Tuple Day HasRemainder
        d = case toEnum $ 1 + fromEnum (day date) of
          Just v -> Tuple v false
          Nothing -> Tuple (unsafePartial $ fromJust $ toEnum 1) true
        m :: Tuple Month HasRemainder
        m = if snd d then
              case toEnum $ 1 + fromEnum (month date) of
                Just v -> Tuple v false
                Nothing -> Tuple (unsafePartial $ fromJust $ toEnum 1) true
            else Tuple (month date) false
        y :: Year
        y = if snd m then
              case toEnum $ 1 + fromEnum (year date) of
                Just v -> v
                -- use 2018 arbitrarly if the conversion from int to Date fails
                Nothing -> unsafePartial $ fromJust $ toEnum 2018
            else (year date)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
import Data.DateTime as DT
import Data.Maybe (maybe)
import Data.Time.Duration (Days(..))

tomorrow :: DT.Date -> DT.Date
tomorrow dt = maybe dt DT.date $ DT.adjust (Days 1.0) (DT.DateTime dt bottom)
```

Although it will return the input date in the unlikely event that the given date is `top` (which is 31st December 275759 if I remember correctly).

There is an `adjust` function for `Time` and `DateTime` so it's just an oversight that `Date` is missing one.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something along those lines

```
getDatePart datepart defaultval1 defaultval2 = 
    case toEnum $ defaultval1 + fromEnum datepart of
    Just v -> Tuple v false
    Nothing -> Tuple (unsafePartial $ fromJust $ toEnum defaultval2) true

getDatePartDefault d datepart defaultval1 defaultval2 =
    if snd d then
        getDatePart datepart defaultval1 defaultval2
    else Tuple datepart false


 tomorrow :: Date -> Date
 tomorrow date = unsafePartial $ canonicalDate (fst y) (fst m) (fst d)
     where d :: Tuple Day HasRemainder
           d = getDatePart (day date) 1 1
           m :: Tuple Month HasRemainder
           m = getDatePartDefault d (month date) 1 1
           y :: Tuple Year HasRemainder
           y = getDatePartDefault d (year date) 1 2018
```

Take care: this is not tested

Answer (score 0):

Using `succ` from `Enum`:

```
import Data.Date (Date)
import Data.Enum (succ)
import Data.Maybe (Maybe)

today :: Date
today = ...

tomorrow :: Maybe Date
tomorrow = succ today
```